# gsutil mb -c standard gs://gcpassignmentapp giving error No command was given Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04, gsutil

user@user-Latitude-E5440:~$ gsutil mb -c standard gs://gcpassignmentapp
No command was given.

Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something.
Try `/usr/bin/gsutil --help' for more information.
user@user-Latitude-E5440:~$

Comment: Can you perform a `gsutil version`? and add the result in your question

Comment: What @guillaumeblaquiere said: this command works just fine for me. Also it seems `gsutil` is a not uncommon application/utility name. You may have some other `gsutil` showing up in your `PATH` first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a different program installed also named gsutil.